# Rest method in wcf service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I want to create method in my WCF service that will return json.

Service code:

```
public interface IParseService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IList<SocialEventDto> GetSocialEvents(int pageNumber = 1);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/socialevents/{pageNumber}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    IList<SocialEventDto> GetSocialEventsJson(string pageNumber);

    [OperationContract]
    IList<ServiceOptionDto> GetServiceOptions();
    //some other methods...
}
```

`web.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="ParserWebRole.ParseService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
                  contract="ParserWebRole.IParseService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

When I try to invoke

```
http://localhost:18549/ParseService.svc/socialevents/1
```

I get

> This webpage is not available

What am I doing wrong?

I saw similar questions but none of them help me.

Comment: i don't think there's any problem.

Comment: see what code yeilds for me http://i.stack.imgur.com/qXD3J.png

Comment: make sure your service url is correct and it's running